# Как сделать редирект при изменении атрибутов?

Tags: java, get, сессия, сервлеты

Нужно при изменении параметра перенаправить пользователя, но кроме этого шакального способа внутри `doGet` не получается ничего больше придумать

```
 while (true)
    {
        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("battle") != null) {
            resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/fight");;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Я смог отловить изменения параметров с помощью `HttpSessionAttributeListener`, но так и не понял, как с помощью этого сделать редирект.

Comment: Какого пользователя? Который меняет атрибуты или какого то другого?

Comment: @RomanC пользователь становиться в очередь и как до него доходит, ему присваиваются атрибуты через session.setAtribute, как ему их присвоили мне надо его перенаправить на другую страничку

Comment: Где код, что  выполняется session.setAtribute?